# Accessing An Element In a List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to access a specific member of a list of tuples in python, for instance I want to get the `fourth` element in the following `tuple` in the list. How do I do that ?

```
[(1, u'2016-11-30 01:57:42', u'X1', u'd1', u'CHECKING', 100000.0)]
```

This list is obtained from a database and therefore the whole code looks like this:

```
 accounts = cur.fetchall()
 logins = cur2.fetchall()
 l = accounts
 l1 = l[0][4]
 print l1
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
 l1 = l[0][4]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use integers to access each index until you arrive at the desired element:

```
>>> l = [(1, u'2016-11-30 01:57:42', u'X1', u'd1', u'CHECKING', 100000.0)]
>>> l[0][3]
'd1'
```

Comment: how do I print it? Because when I call print with this ı get the following error: list index out of range

Comment: @comsfollower - Then you have a different list, or are accessing it in a way other than shown here.

Comment: So I received this from a database and therefore the whole code looks like this accounts = cur.fetchall();
        l = accounts;
        l1 = l[0][4];
        print l1

Comment: Please do print(l)

Comment: print(l) works but I want to print l1, i.e. the fourth element of the tuple

Comment: The `print(l)` will aid us in debugging your error... Can you please post the output of it?

Comment: Sure sorry, this is the output: [(1, u'2016-11-30 03:29:48', u'X1', u'd1', u'CHECKING', 100000.0)]

Comment: No problem :). On my end, `[(1, u'2016-11-30 03:29:48', u'duru', u'duru', u'CHECKING', 100000.0)][0][3]` works fine.

Comment: well i am still getting the same error; thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Take the first index of the list, your tuple, and then the fourth index of the tuple.

```
[(1, u'2016-11-30 01:57:42', u'X1', u'd1', u'CHECKING', 100000.0)][0][3]
```